# Error: Unknown property 'OpportunityStandardController.Stage'

Tags: visualforce, error

while creating stage picklist am getting this error..please help me to resolve ..

```
<apex:pageblockSectionitem>
  <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!Stage }"> 
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!Stage }">
   </apex:selectOptions>
  </apex:selectList>
</apex:pageblockSectionitem>
```

Comment: Try `{!Opportunity.Stage}`.

Comment: instead `apex:selectlist` use `<apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Stage}" />`  This will create picklist for you..

Comment: added but   am getting another error after added that line of code      like                                                                                        Error: Could not resolve field 'Stage' from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!Opportunity.Stage}' in page MyOpportunities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API name for standard `Stage` field on `Opportunity` object is `StageName`